# iPhone: UnitTest Simulate Click

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to write unit tests to my app. Is there any way to simulate click ? Can somebody write a simple code? Lets say I have just a button, how to simulate click on a button ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Automating iOS User Interface Testing with UIAutomation](http://altf.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/automating-ios-user-interface-testing-with-uiautomation/)